# Most efficient way to calculate log base 2

Tags: binary

I recently started learning stuff with bits and now while I was solving one problem, I started thinking what is the most efficient way to calculate $$\lfloor \log_{2}K\rfloor$$

**What I started thinking**

It is clear that we can calculate log in $O(\log K)$. Here is my code for example

```
long long a;
long long result = 0;
for(long long i=0;i<63;i++) {
    if((1LL<<i)<=a) {
        result = i;
    }
}
```

Then I started thinking that something with bits can help, actually we want to find the leftmost bit in the whole binary number, then I found out about the function `__builtin_clz(x):` this function returns the zeroes at the beggining of the binary number, so if there are $x$ zeros at the beginning we can say that the log is $N - x$ where $N$ is the total number of bits in the number. I don't know the complexity of this function, but I think that it is $O(\log K)$.

Is there better way to calculate log in c++?

Comment: since __builtin_clz doesn't work for arbitrarily large numbers (you're limited by the processor architecture, so 64 bits or so?), it takes O(1). Asymptotic runtime only becomes interesting if you use something like gmp integers.

Comment: [Bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) is also in general a nice resource.

Comment: I want to calculate log only for integers that fit in long long, that is all integers less than 2^64 - 1

Comment: If you are certain that your C++ code will be built using a compiler that supports the mentioned builtin, then definitely use it. It will likely compile down to a single, efficient instruction whenever applicable on an architecture. However, you may need to assert the input is non-zero (otherwise __builtin_clz as well as log itself both have undefined behavior). Also, did you mean N - x - 1?